# How to disable onclick when applying onclick on the other item

Tags: javascript

Here is my Script,so when I click the first item with a unique id it loads the data but when i click the other item that uses the same function it is added to the first one so i want only the one I  click to appear and the other one must be hidden this is inside toggle_visibility.

```
function toggle_visibility(id){
  var e = document.getElementById(id);   
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display='none';
  else
    (e.style.display = 'inline-block')
}
```

Comment: If you're passing different IDs, different calls to `toggle_visibility` shouldn't affect any other elements. Be sure that you have unique IDs everywhere and that you're calling the function with the proper ID.

Comment: I am working with a south african map so each provice has a specific ID but when I click on another province the data for the previus province still appear on the screen and I want to see only a clicked provice data only on the screen

Comment: Oh, like that. I can't point you to specific things right now but I think you're best off looking into jQuery functions for this, rather than trying to build this from scratch. I'll gladly give it a shot if no answer is posted in a few hours time.

Answer (score 0):

you want to show the clicked control only and want to hide all the other controls in document.
for this you can use below given function(here i am assuming the control is DIV and using jQuery ):-

```
   function toggle_visibility(id){
     $("div").hide();//current passing div or you can pass any tag or selector to hide
     $(id).show();//to show the id's control
   }
```

above given function will hide all the DIV's except the passed one.